# Product of coset groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H, K$ two normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G = HK$ then for each $ (gH, g'K) \in (G / H) \times (G /K) $ there exists $a \in G$ such that $ ( gH, g'K) = (aH, aK) $

Hi, there I have no idea how to find this element $a$ I've tried this: $( gH, g'K) = (aH, aK) \Leftrightarrow gH = aH$ and $ g'K = aK \Leftrightarrow ga^{-1} \in H $ and $g'a^{-1} \in K$ but I don't know how to continue I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Try writing $g=hk$, $g'=h'k'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want $gH = aH$ and $g'K = aK$, then by the definition of cosets we must have
$$a = gh,\ a = g'k$$
for some $(h,k)\in H \times K$. It is not immediately obvious that this is possible, but we can try to work backward to the solution.

To have $a = gh$ and $a = g'k$ we must have $gh = g'k$. This is equivalent to
$$hk^{-1} = g^{-1}g'$$
But because $HK = G$ we know it is always possible to find $h,k$ that satisfy this.

Now to construct the solution, we start with the result that $HK = G$ implies
$$\exists (h,k)\in H \times K \mid g^{-1}g' = hk$$
Thus we have $gh = g'k^{-1}$. If we let $a = gh = g'k^{-1}$ then we get our solution.